# Instantiate DateTime object based on today's date but different hour, minute and seconds component

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to create a new DateTime object with today's date but different Time component. Here is how I am currently doing it

```
DateTime oddStart = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month,  DateTime.Now.Day,
                                            0,0,0);
```

Is there any better-looking way of doing it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write

```
var date = DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds));
```

If you just want to set hours, minutes and seconds to zero then you don't even need the `.Add()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

or

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Today;
```

These both return today's date with setting the time components all to zero.

If you want a non-zero, custom time component, you can do the following:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 2, 3)); // 18/09/2013 01:02:03
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the constructor is for, but I would capture the `DateTime.Now` as a separate parameter:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var myDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

Otherwise the value might change in between providing the arguments.

If all you want is a date with a zero time, there is a `.Date` property on the `DateTime`.

The are various *alternative* ways of doing it, but I wouldn't go so far as to say any are better than others. Whatever is most readable would be a good thing to aim for initially.